# Form not parsing correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, url, redirect

I am having a ton of trouble with parsing A custom form that I created in wordpress,  I am on a page called `front-page.php` where my form is located and the parser is on a page called `formhandler.php`, I have my parser running from a seperate page.

I am really confused because the form itself is recognizing the parser on the other page, just not actually parsing the data and taking you to the correct page.  I get a long unknown URL that takes me to a 404 page within the site itself.

I need help figuring out why this forms code is not working or if the parser is just not in the right location to actually do the parsing work. I am fairly new to wordpress so anything helps right now.  I have to get this done right now for my client, any help would be awesome. I just haven't had to use a custom form within WordPress before.

```
URL:

http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/formhandler.php?selection=http%3A%2F%2F50.22.79.62%2F~pftech%2Fwater-delivery-service%2F&zip=92115&home=on&did_submit=Get+Started%21


FORM PARSER:
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego =  array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173');

        if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
            header("Location: ".urldecode($_GET['selection'])."?zip=".$_GET['zip']."&type=".$_GET['type']);
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
        }
        exit;
    }
?>



FORM:
<form method='get' id='gform_1' action='front-page.php'>
  <div class="serviceinput">
    <label for="services">Services: </label>
    <select id="selection" name="selection">
      <option value=''>Select a Service</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/'>Water Delivery</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/'>Coffee Services</option>
      <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/'>Water Filtration</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="zipcode">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
    <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" />
  </div>
  <div class="frontradio">
    <input name="type" type="radio" id="homeradio" value="home" />
    <div class="homelabel"> <label for="homeradio">Home</label></div>
    <input name="type" type="radio" id="officeradio" value="office" />
    <label for="officeradio">Office</label>
  </div>
  <div class="homebutton">
    <input type='submit' id="submithome" name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that in the action, you have front-page.php which is the name of the form file. is this what you want to have? 404 means that the page is not found.

I believe you should try action='formhandler.php'. After is found, you can check your parser.

Comment: No I have already changed that actually that was one of the first things I did. I originally had it on the same page than I moved it over and forgot to update it on here, so that has already been done and I am getting the exact same URL.  I think it has something to do with wordpress and how wordpress handles a parsing file or if it even can handle those on its own?  Does anyone know if Wordpress can  parse your custom forms for you just on an external php file to that form, as well as being on the root level as well.   I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY I CANNON GET THIS SIMPLE FORM TO PARSE PLEASE HELP

Comment: ? Any help with this question in general would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i don't know how wordpress is working. but, 404 means it's not found. you parser is not reached at all. and having the form sending the action in the same file is not a good idea, but you fixed this already. maybe it needs a path for the parser file, to find it. Are both files in the same folder?

Comment: It wasn't exactly a 404 message if you go that URL posted its more or less just a lost page and says no posts found.  Not a 404. Yes these two files are on the same root level as well.  I am pretty sure it has something to do with wordpress handling the parser, but I am not certain.  I am suprised someone hasn't mentioned something like that yet.  But IDK, it is reaching the parser because the redirected URL shows formhandler.php in the Url on that page it goes to.  It is working but not displaying correctly and I am unsure why?  ANY IDEAS ANYONE ON WHAT THE PROBLEM MIGHT BE HERE.ANYTHINGHELPS